# Evaluating $\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)^{i\eta/2} u^{i\eta/2}$ for real $u<0$ and $\eta>0$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, branch-cuts

> Let $u$ and $\eta$ be real numbers such that $u<0$ and $\eta>0$. What is the value of this expression?
> $$\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)^{i\eta/2} u^{i\eta/2}$$

This is probably trivial, but the result I got from Mathematica is Abs[...] = $e^{-\pi \eta}$. I am not sure how to obtain this result properly.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AmorFati what is the value of such quantity (just clarified the question)

Comment: @arthur Something went wrong in the comment's formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main "trick" is to use the definition:
$$
z^w = e^{w\text{Log}(z)}
$$
for any complex numbers $z,w$, where $\text{Log}(z)$ refers to the principal branch of the complex logarithm:
$$
\text{Log}(z) = \ln|z| + i\text{Arg}z
$$

As an example, take $z = u$ and $w = i\eta/2$. Hence,
$$
u^{i\eta/2} = e^{\frac{i\eta}{2}\text{Log}(u)}
$$
But,
$$
\text{Log}(u) = \ln|u| + i\pi
$$
since $u<0$ (thus $\text{Arg}(u)=\pi$). It follows that
$$
u^{i\eta/2} = e^{\frac{i\eta}{2}\ln|u| } e^{-\frac{\eta\pi}{2}}
$$
In a very similar way, and using $\ln|1/u| = -\ln|u|$ we obtain:
$$
\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)^{i\eta/2} = e^{-\frac{i\eta}{2}\ln|u| } e^{-\frac{\eta\pi}{2}}
$$
Thus,
$$
\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)^{i\eta/2}u^{i\eta/2} = \left( e^{-\frac{i\eta}{2}\ln|u| } e^{\frac{i\eta}{2}\ln|u| }\right)\left(e^{-\frac{\eta\pi}{2}} e^{-\frac{\eta\pi}{2}}\right) = e^{-\eta\pi}
$$
Hopefully I didn't make any mistake and this is helpful to you.

Comment: More than an identity, that's the definition of $z^w$

Comment: thanks, I'll change that

Comment: I see, thanks! I was jumping off a branch using $\ln(\frac{1}{u}) =\ln(\frac{1}{|u| e^{i \pi}}) = \ln(\frac{e^{-i \pi}}{|u|})$